# Read contents of a file with the Javascript File API with a file URL instead of file input

Tags: javascript, fileapi

All examples I see on the HTML5/JS File API read the file by letting the user select the file first using

```
<input type="file">
```

I want to be able to read the contents of the file using a URL/path to the file. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done from the browser for security purposes.